# Checking each element and changing it based on parent (JavaScript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a case, where I need to dynamically change the background of a list items based on the background of a closest parent element with a `.box` class. If that parent also has `.gray` class, replace the current background of the span elements within this list to a dark background, else, to white. 
I tried this approach (code below), and it returns the right amount of trues and falses, but the if/then part wont work, it just replaces the background colour in all elements, not just within one list.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.box-list li span').each(function(){ 
  var is_gray = $(this).closest('.box').hasClass('gray'); 
   console.log (is_gray);
  
  if (is_gray = true) {
   $('.box-list li span').css('background', '#999');
  }
  else {
   $('.box-list li span').css('background', '#fff');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.box-list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
 width: 100%; 
}
.box-list li:before {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    content:"· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ""· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ""· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ""· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ""· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · "
}
.box-list li span:nth-child(2) {
    float: right;
}
.box-list li {
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.box-list li:last-child {
 margin: 0 !important;
}
.box-list li span {
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.box { 
 padding-right: 3rem;
 padding-left: 3rem;
 padding-top: 1.5rem !important; 
 padding-bottom: 3rem !important;
}
.box.gray {
 background: #efefef !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "box gray">
  <div>
    <ul class="box-list">
      <li>
        <span>
          List item
        </span>
        <span>
          1
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          Another list item
        </span>
        <span>
          2
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          And another one
        </span>
        <span>
          3
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          And one more
        </span>
        <span>
          4
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          Secont to last list item
        </span>
        <span>
          5
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          The last list item
        </span>
        <span>
          6
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
 
<div class = "box">
  <div>
    <ul class="box-list">
      <li>
        <span>
          List item
        </span>
        <span>
          1
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          Another list item
        </span>
        <span>
          2
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          And another one
        </span>
        <span>
          3
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          And one more
        </span>
        <span>
          4
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          Secont to last list item
        </span>
        <span>
          5
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          The last list item
        </span>
        <span>
          6
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not getting the purpose of jQuery here... 
Why don't you use pure CSS? Something like

```
.box .box-list li span {
  background: white;
}
.box.gray .box-list li span {
  background: gray;
}
```

This will work, unless you want to get the parent's background color dynamically. In this case the answers below aren't correct as well.

---

If your issue is to set the background in some-specific situation (so you don't want this behaviour always), I'd try to use jQuery only for adding/removing a class, i.e.

```
//click or whatever you expect
$('#button').click( flagBox );
function flagBox(){
  $('#theBox').addClass('active');
}
```

And CSS

```
.box.active .box-list li span {
  background: white;
}
.box.active.gray .box-list li span {
  background: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_gray = true) {
```

You're using `=` instead of `==`.
`=` assigns a new value, making the `if` pointless.

Answer (score 0):

target the individual elements instead of all the ones with the class when applying the background color using `$(this)` instead of `$('.box-list li span')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.box-list li span').each(function(){   
  if ($(this).closest('.box').hasClass('gray')) {
   $(this).css('background', '#999');
  }
  else {
   $(this).css('background', '#fff');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.box-list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
 width: 100%; 
}
.box-list li:before {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    content:"· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ""· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ""· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ""· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ""· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · · "
}
.box-list li span:nth-child(2) {
    float: right;
}
.box-list li {
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.box-list li:last-child {
 margin: 0 !important;
}
.box-list li span {
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.box { 
 padding-right: 3rem;
 padding-left: 3rem;
 padding-top: 1.5rem !important; 
 padding-bottom: 3rem !important;
}
.box.gray {
 background: #efefef !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "box gray">
  <div>
    <ul class="box-list">
      <li>
        <span>
          List item
        </span>
        <span>
          1
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          Another list item
        </span>
        <span>
          2
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          And another one
        </span>
        <span>
          3
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          And one more
        </span>
        <span>
          4
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          Secont to last list item
        </span>
        <span>
          5
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          The last list item
        </span>
        <span>
          6
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
 
<div class = "box">
  <div>
    <ul class="box-list">
      <li>
        <span>
          List item
        </span>
        <span>
          1
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          Another list item
        </span>
        <span>
          2
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          And another one
        </span>
        <span>
          3
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          And one more
        </span>
        <span>
          4
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          Secont to last list item
        </span>
        <span>
          5
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>
          The last list item
        </span>
        <span>
          6
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code seems realy slow to me, you look for each item if it has an class.
Working example with your code:

```
var $box = $('.box-list li span');
  $box.each(function(){
    if( $(this).parents('.box').hasClass('gray') ) {
      $(this).css('background', 'grey');
    }
    else {
      $(this).css('background', 'red');
    }
  });
```

but it seems easier and faster to check if an element has a children and then add the color all children.

```
var $box = $('.box')
  $box.each(function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass('gray') ) {
      $(this).find('span').css('background', 'grey')
    }
    else {
     $(this).find('span').css('background', 'red')
    }
  });
```